# I need to directly open the edit form for a particular record in a jqgrid from another page

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, coldfusion, cfwheels

I need to open the edit form for a particular record in a jqgrid from another page.

Do I need to capture the load event in jqgrid then pull the id out of the URL and manually select the record or is there an easier way?

Due to paging the record is not likely to be on the page at all when it loads.

The key column is "BLS_ID"

here is the code that opens the page:

```
function OpenInNewTab()
{    
  var bls_id = '#BLS.bls_id#';    
  var win=window.open('#URLFOR(controller="realty", action="rpi_data_sheet_view")#?template=RPI_Deleted_BLS&BLS_ID='+bls_id, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

here is the code from the jqgrid page:

```
<cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.BlockUI.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // called by grid-wrapper when form is shown
    function setup_archived_installations_table_form(form) {
        var form = $(form);

        form.find('##AREA').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##INST_NAME').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##BLS_NO').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##SUB_NO').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##TRANS_DESCRIP_2').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##USE_DESC').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##DET_DESC').hfds('disable');
        form.find('##RP_CODE').hfds('disable');

        form.attr("permissionsObject", "b_bls_disposition");
        applyFormPermissions();

        //form.find('select').width(160).hfds('wideSelectFix');

        $('##DISP_DATE').addClass("date-picker");

        setup_form_elements();

        // disable everything but trans_code
        //form.find('input, select[name != "TRANS_CODE"]').hfds('disable');
    }

    $(function() {
         $('##disposition_btn').click(function() {
            var modal = $('##disposition_modal');
            var selected = $('##archived_installations_table').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

            modal.load('#URLFor(action="disposition_form", params="bls_id=")#' + selected, function() {
                $(this).find('.date-picker').addClass("date-picker");

                modal.dialog({
                    title: 'Disposition-related Fields',
                    modal: true,
                    width: 500
                });
            });
        });

        $('##disposition_form form').live('submit', function(e) {
            var self = $(this);
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            var modal = $('##disposition_modal');

            modal.block({message: ''});

            $.ajax({
                url: self.attr('action'),
                data: self.serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function() {
                    $('##archived_installations_table').trigger('reloadGrid');
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Failed to file disposition');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    modal.unblock();
                    modal.dialog('close');
                }
            });

            /*
             *$.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
             *    $('##building_datasheet_table').trigger('reloadGrid');
             *    modal.unblock();
             *    modal.dialog('close');
             *});
             */

            return false;
        }) 
    });
</script>

<h1 class="title">Deleted Buildings, Structures, Lands</h1>

<cfsavecontent variable="BuildingTableDef">
    {
        "height": "auto",

                "autowidth" : true,
                "shrinkToFit" : false,

        "gridview": true,
        "url":"#URLFor(action="jqGrid_get", params="modelName=BLS&customSQLMethod=BLSDatasheet(0,1)")#", 
        "editurl": "#URLFor(action='saveDeletedBLS')#",
        "datatype": "json",
        "rowNum": "10", 
        "pager": "##archived_installations_pager",
        "jsonReader": {
                        "root": "ROWS",
                        "page": "PAGE",
                        "total": "TOTAL",
                        "record": "RECORDS",
                        "repeatitems": false
                    },
        "colModel":[
            { "name" : "AREA", "width": "100", "label": "Area", "editable": true, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "formatter": "select", "editoptions": {
                "value": "#jqGridValueString(areas, "area_code", "area_name")#"
            }},
            { "name" : "INST_NO", "width": "75" },
            { "name" : "INST_NAME", "editable": true },
                    { "name" : "PROP_TYPE", "label": "Prop Type", "formatter": "select", "editable": false, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(prop_types, "prop_type", "prop_desc")#"
                    }},
            { "name" : "STATE", "width": "50" },
            { "name" : "COUNTY" },
            { "name" : "CITY_TOWN" },
            { "name" : "BLS_NO", "width": "75", "editable": true },
            { "name" : "SUB_NO", "width": "75", "editable": true },
            { "name" : "TRANS_CODE", "width": "75", "editable": true, "edittype": "select", "search": false, "editoptions": {
                "value": "#jqGridValueString(trans_codes, "trans_code2", "trans_descrip2")#"
            }},
            { "name" : "TRANS_DESCRIP_2", "label": "Action", "editable": true },
            { "name" : "USE_DESC", "label": "Use Desc", "editable": true, "edittype": "select",  "stype": "select", "editoptions": {
                "value": "#jqGridValueString(b_use_descs, "use_desc")#"
            }},
            { "name" : "DET_DESC", "label": "Detailed Desc", "editable": true },
            { "name" : "RP_CODE", "width": "75", "label": "RP Code", "editable": true },
            { "name" : "GSM", "width": "75", "label": "GSM", "align":"right", "formatter": "number", "formatoptions":{"decimalSeparator":".", "thousandsSeparator": ",", "decimalPlaces": 2, "defaultValue": "0.0"} },
            { "name" : "GSF", "width": "75", "label": "GSF", "align":"right", "formatter": "number", "formatoptions":{"decimalSeparator":".", "thousandsSeparator": ",", "decimalPlaces": 2, "defaultValue": "0.0"} },
            { "name" : "BLDG_CNT", "width": "75", "align":"right", "label": "No Bldgs"},

                    { "name" : "STEW_CODE", "label": "Steward", "editable": false, "formatter": "select", "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(stewards, "stew_code", "stew_description")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "POTEN_OWNER", "label": "Poten Owner", "editable": false },
                    { "name" : "CNTRCT_ARNGMT", "label": "Contract Arrangement", "formatter": "select", "editable": false, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(contract_arrangements, "cntrct_arngmt", "cntrct_arngmt_desc")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "EST_CST_IND", "label": "Est. Cost Indicator", "formatter": "select", "editable": false, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(est_costs, "code", "code_descr")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "NEG_CST_IND", "label": "Neg. Cost Indicator", "formatter": "select", "editable": false, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(neg_costs, "code", "code_descr")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "COND", "label": "Condition", "editable": false, "formatter": "select", "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(conditions, "cond", "cond_desc")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "CNSTR", "label": "Construction", "editable": false, "formatter": "select", "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(constructions, "cnstr", "constr_desc")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "DISP", "label": "Disposal", "formatter": "select", "editable": false, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(disposals, "disp", "disp_desc")#"
                    }},
                    { "name" : "STAND", "label": "Standard", "formatter": "select", "editable": false, "edittype": "select", "stype":"select", "editoptions": {
                        "value": "#jqGridValueString(standards, "stand", "stand_desc")#"
                    }},             

            { "name" : "DISP_METHOD", "label": "Disp Method", "editable": true,
                "edittype": "select","formatter": "select","stype":"select",
                "editoptions": {
                    "value": "#jqGridValueString(disp_meths, "disp_code", "disp_desc")#"
                }
            },
            { "name" : "DISP_DATE", "align": "right", "label": "Disp Date", 
                "datefmt": "mm/dd/yyyy",
                "formatter": "date",
                "formatoptions": { "srcformat": "F, d y H:i:s", "newformat": "m/d/Y" },  
                "editable": true, "editrules": {
                "edithidden": true
            }},
            { "name" : "DISP_VALUE", "label": "Disp Value", "align":"right", "editable": true, "editrules": {
                    "edithidden": true, "number": true
                },
                "formatter": "number",
                "formatoptions":{"decimalSeparator":".", "thousandsSeparator": "", "decimalPlaces": 2, "prefix": ""}
            },
            { "name" : "NET_PROCEEDS", "label": "Net Proceeds", "align":"right", "editable": true, "editrules": {
                    "edithidden": true, "number": true
                },
                "formatter": "number",
                "formatoptions":{"decimalSeparator":".", "thousandsSeparator": "", "decimalPlaces": 2, "prefix": ""}
            },
            { "name" : "RECIPENT", "label": "Recipient", "editable": true, "editrules": {
                "edithidden": true
            }},
            { "name" : "ADDRESS_ID2", "width": "50", "label": "Addr ID" },
            { "name" : "BLS_ID", "width": "50", "label": "BLS ID", "key": true }
        ],
        "caption": "Real Property - Buildings" 
    }
</cfsavecontent>

<cfsavecontent variable="tableEventListeners">
ondblClickRow: function(id){

  $('##archived_installations_table').jqGrid('editGridRow', id, { 
      closeAfterEdit: true,
      recreateForm: true,

        afterShowForm: function (id) {
            if (typeof setup_archived_installations_table_form === 'function') {
                setup_archived_installations_table_form(id);
            }

            $(":input", id).each(function() { 
                $this = $(this);
                $this.data("originalValue", $this.val());

                $this.wrap("<div class='jqGridFormField' />");
                $this.bind("change keyup", function () {
                    $wrapper = $(this).parent("div.jqGridFormField");
                    if ($(this).val() != $(this).data("originalValue"))
                        $wrapper.addClass("jqGridFormFieldChanged");    
                    else
                        $wrapper.removeClass("jqGridFormFieldChanged");         
                });
            });

        } 

  });
}

</cfsavecontent>

<cfset perms = model('BLSDisposition').getPermissions()>
<cfsavecontent variable="pagerDef">
            {
                <cfif ListFindNoCase(perms.objectPermissions, "UPDATE")>
                edit: true,
                <cfelse>
                edit: false,
                </cfif>
                add: false,
                del: false,
                search: true,
                editfunc: function(id) {
                    $('##archived_installations_table').jqGrid('editGridRow', id, { 
                        closeAfterEdit: true,
                        recreateForm: true,
                        onInitializeForm: function(id) {
                            if (typeof setup_archived_installations_table_form === 'function') {
                                setup_archived_installations_table_form(id);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 
            {}, //  default settings for edit
            {}, //  default settings for add
            {},  // delete instead that del:false we need this
            {
                closeAfterSearch: true,
                multipleSearch: true,
                multipleGroup: true
            }, // search options
            {} /* view parameters*/ 
</cfsavecontent>    

#jqGridWrapper(accessibleView=IsDefined("session.user.is_notified") AND IsBoolean(session.user.is_notified) AND session.user.is_notified,
            modelName="BLS", 
            footerRow="true",
            filterToolbar="true",
            tableID="archived_installations_table",
            pagerID="archived_installations_pager",
    exportToExcelOption="true",
            pagerDefinition="#pagerDef#",
            tableDefinitionJSON='#BuildingTableDef#',
    tableEventListeners='#tableEventListeners#')#
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Had to add the following to tableEventListeners:

```
    gridComplete: function(){
    var blsid=(decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + 'BLS_ID' + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|##|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null);
    if(blsid!=null){
        $('##archived_installations_table').jqGrid('editGridRow', blsid);
    }
},
```

Comment: I spoke too soon. This doesn't work for records whose ID is not currently displayed in the grid. (like if it's on another page)